# error: couldn't read version from server

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting the following error when trying to run `kubectl` locally.

`error: couldn't read version from server: Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused`

I know this relates to the kubectl config but I'm at a loss in how to resolve it.  2 days ago, I was experimenting with GKE and did set the config to point to GCE.  I tried deleting this config file and then getting [Vagrant with CoreOS locally](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster).  This `vagrant up` throws a similar error complaining about not being able to connect.

What is the appropriate way to instrument `kubectl` so it can connect to the API and return information?

Answer (score 15):

**tl;dr** `gcloud container get-credentials --cluster=CLUSTER_ID --zone=YOURZONE`

---

So a little background: the kubectl tool is developed by google but isn't actually integrated into google cloud directly, the google cloud just helps you get a compatible version with it when you tell it to install the component.

If you're getting the `Get http://localhost:8080/api: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connection refused` it is likely due to the `kubectl` tool not being configured at all or misconfigured. What I believe it's trying to do is assuming you have kubernetes somehow setup locally only, which you don't in this case since it's all on the google cloud (hence the cryptic error).

You can verify your kubectl is misconfigured by running `kubectl config view`. If it's correctly configured you should see things like a few entries in cluster, with ip addresses, and in users you should see a user for each project, etc. If you see nothing of the sort (ie. empty clusters, and empty users) then you are misconfigured; you will also encounter cryptic issues if you dont see entries for the specific cluster you are trying to work on.

Annoyingly a lot of `gcloud` commands will silently auto-configure it for you, so if you follow something like a hello wordpress tutorial it will look like you dont have to do this and that somehow kubectl communicates with gcloud, but nothing of the sort happens. It's also very easy to lose that configuration.

To tell gcloud to give you the kubectl config run the following:

```
gcloud container get-credentials --cluster=CLUSTER_ID --zone=YOURZONE
```

For cluster id run `gcloud container clusters list`

Zone is "europe-west1-d" or whatever you've chosen.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  I do have kubernetes set up locally and have been trying to play with it more by using vagrant.  If I have a Vagrant cluster with nodes running the api server, control manager, and scheduler, how do I configure `kubectl` to recognize that?  Here's a portion of my `kubectl config view`.  - cluster:
    server: ""
  name: vagrant
contexts:.  This doesn't show up well in the comments but it doesn't have any details, just the "vagrant" name I gave it.

Comment: See also https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations?hl=de#passing_cluster_credentials_to_kubectl

Comment: But wasn't the original question why `kubectl` cannot connect to the local Vagrant-based cluster?

Comment: The `beta` in `gcloug beta container` isn't necessary anymore. The `beta` component is still available though. Also, `view` has become `list`, as in `gcloud config list`.

Answer (score 9):

This used to be `beta`, but that is no longer the case. So the command now is:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> --zone=<zone-of-cluster> --project=<project-id>
```

If you try to run it with the `beta` command you get the following error message:

> WARNING: You invoked `gcloud beta`, but with current configuration Kubernetes Engine v1 API will be used instead of v1beta1 API.
>   `gcloud beta` will switch to use Kubernetes Engine v1beta1 API by default by the end of March 2018.

Later on if you wish to switch between clusters via `kubectl` (only for ones that you have already authenticated for), you can use:

```
kubectl config use-context gke_<project-name>_<zone>_<cluster>
```

Example:

```
kubectl config use-context gke_my-project_europe-west1-c_my-cluster
```

To see where you currently are:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

The above solution no longer works. You need to do the following instead:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> \
    [--zone=<zone-of-cluster> --project=<project-id>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Google Container Engine (GKE) and got this error, too. In my case, it was because I forgot to create a container cluster first.

If you [create a cluster using the gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/guestbook#create_a_container_engine_cluster), it sets the config for the you.

```
gcloud container clusters create my-cluster-name
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when deploying locally with a mostly default configuration on Ubuntu Trusty. Turns out the api-server was not starting due to some bug with 
`DenyEscalatingExec` particular to ubuntu in k8s v1.1.7

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14474
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/14627

I rebuilt the cluster without it by removing the directive from the file `~/kubernetes-1.1.7/cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh` before executing `kube-up.sh`

```
# Admission Controllers to invoke prior to persisting objects in cluster
export ADMISSION_CONTROL=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota,DenyEscalatingExec,SecurityContextDeny
```

DenyEscalatingExec needs to be removed from that line, and as a result, it won't be a flag in your `/etc/default/kube-apiserver` after starting the cluster.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure what DenyEscalatingExec does, I just found that this worked for me to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

This is in flux, just reference the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials?hl=en_US&_ga=1.141878517.670927791.1459877980). It is currently ...

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials NAME [--zone ZONE, -z ZONE] [GLOBAL-FLAG …]
```