# Using kubectl for local development without gcloud?

Tags: vagrant, gcloud, kubernetes

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573402/error-couldnt-read-version-from-server), I was wondering if there are any plans to be able to use the kubectl tool without installing gcloud?

The use case I have in mind is the same as the one that fellow had: [running kubernetes on CoreOS locally via vagrant](https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-vagrant-coreos-cluster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use kubectl without gcloud. You can download the latest official Kubernetes release from its [releases page on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/releases), then run kubectl by untarring it and either running `./cluster/kubectl.sh` or copying the kubectl binary from `platforms/$OS/$ARCHITECTURE/kubectl` into your shell's path.

Also, setting up Kubernetes on vagrant can be as simple as running these two commands, which should get everything in place for you:

`export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  For my test cluster, I ended up using the default vagrantfile shipped with the Kubernetes release (running Fedora).  I think the CoreOS example might need a bit of reworking.  Also, it was necessary to install the latest version of the kubectl command line tool in /usr/local/bin .

Comment: So I need two kubectl binaries to target local and gcloud clusters?

Comment: No, the kubectl installed by gcloud is exactly the same as the one that you can install directly. There's no benefit to having both. You can change which cluster kubectl talks to using the `kubectl config` commands - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config.md